# MailAddress class needs more headers to be reliable

Tags: .net

I want to send mail in my website. Also, want to make MailMessage.From property friendly. Furthermore, I can't send message except for gmail.
But with gmail, I am able to send messages hotmail etc. All-the-same, I can't send mail with friendly names even by using gmail. As a result of these, I thing so that MailMessage.Headers property has no enough headers to be reliable, it isn't transmited cross mail services.

> CSharp codes:

```
public static void SendMail(string subject, string body, params string[] to)
    {
        string password = "********";
        string userName = "userName@host.com";
        bool isBodyHtml = true;
        string from = "\"displayName\" <userName@host.com>";
        int port = 587;
        string host = "smtp.host.com";
        bool enableSSL = true;
        var credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            credential.Password = password;
            credential.UserName = userName;
            using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
            {
                mm.Subject = subject;
                mm.Body = body;
                mm.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
                for (int i = 0; i < to.Count(); i++)
                {
                    mm.To.Add(to[i]);
                }
                mm.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from);
                var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Credentials = credential;
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                    smtp.Port = port;
                    smtp.Host = host;
                    smtp.Send(mm);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm ok so what is the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out [MailAddress Constructor (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s17zfkf.aspx) the first parameter is the email address and the second paramter is the display name of the email address.

Comment: No problem while instantiating

Comment: -1 That's not it. `new MailAddress("\"displayName\" <userName@host.com>")` and `new MailAddress("<userName@host.com>", "displayName");` result in identical objects being created.

Comment: This works for me `new MailAddress("username@host.com", "User Name")`.  I tried sending an email to GMail and Exchange and both showed up with "User Name" as the display name.